# PWA Install button using React - Android

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I want to be able to install the web app on the android Apps screen. I need some sort of hook  that I can use on the installAndroid function.

This is what I have done so far:

P.S I am a beginner in using React, so any help would be appreciated.

Resources which I have been looking at:
https://blog.wick.technology/pwa-install-prompt/

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import PlusIcon from '../../../assets/icons/plus_icon.svg'
import ShareIcon from '../../../assets/icons/share_icon.svg'

const PromptMobile = () => {

    const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

    function handleWindowSizeChange() {
        setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowSizeChange);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowSizeChange);
        }
    }, []);

    const isMobile = width <= 768;


    const [myBool, setmyBool] = useState(true);

    function toggleBool() {
      setmyBool(!myBool)
    }
  
    if (isMobile && /iPhone|iPad/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
        return (
            myBool ? <PromptAddIOS toggleBool={toggleBool} /> : <PromptInstructionsIOS /> 
        );
    } 
    else if (isMobile && /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) 
    {
        return (
            <InstallAndroid />
        );
    } 
    else{
        return null;
    }
}
  
  function PromptAddIOS(props){
    return (
        <div className='prompt-mobile__child'>
            <span>Click here to add this app to your home screen</span>
            <button className='red-button' onClick={props.toggleBool}>Add</button>
        </div>
    )
  }
  
  function PromptInstructionsIOS(){
    return (
    <div className='prompt-mobile__child'>
        <p>To install this app on your device tap the Menu button<img style={{marginLeft:'10px'}} src={ShareIcon} alt="Plus Icon"/></p> 
        <p>then hit 'Add to Home screen' button  <img style={{marginLeft:'10px'}} src={PlusIcon} alt="Share Icon"/></p> 
    </div>
    )
  }

  function InstallAndroid(){
    return (
        <div className='prompt-mobile__child'>
            <p>Install this website as a web app on your Apps screen?</p>
            <button className="red-button">Install</button>
        </div>
        )
  }

export default PromptMobile;
```

Comment: Maybe this is what I need - https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/react-use-pwa-install ... any suggestions?